# Problems install mongodb using image php:8.0.10 alpine

Tags: php, mongodb, docker, dockerfile, php-8

Problem installing mongodb, dockerfile using php:8.0.10-alpine image

```
running: make
/bin/sh /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserdIJeIa/mongodb-1.10.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -Isrc/libmongoc/src/common/ -I/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/libmongoc/src/common/ -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserdIJeIa/mongodb-1.10.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuserdIJeIa/mongodb-1.10.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/libmongoc/src/common/ -I/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/libmongoc/src/libbson/src/ -I/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/libmongoc/src/libbson/src/jsonsl/ -I/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/libmongoc/src/libmongoc/src/ -I/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/libmongocrypt/src/ -I/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/libmongocrypt/kms-message/src/ -I/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/libmongocrypt-compat/ -I/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/BSON/ -I/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/MongoDB/ -I/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/MongoDB/Exception/ -
I/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/MongoDB/Monitoring/ -I/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/contrib/  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2    -DBSON_COMPILATION -DMONGOC_COMPILATION     -DKMS_MESSAGE_ENABLE_CRYPTO=1 -DKMS_MESSAGE_ENABLE_CRYPTO_LIBCRYPTO=1   -c /tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/src/libmongoc/src/common/common-b64.c -o src/libmongoc/src/common/common-b64.lo
make: /bin/sh: Operation not permitted
make: *** [Makefile:277: src/libmongoc/src/common/common-b64.lo] Error 127
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0.10-alpine     && \
     pecl install mongodb \
     pecl clear-cache \
     && \
    echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mongodb.ini; \
```

Comment: Could you share your Dockerfile as well?

Comment: using the error code it seems either this file is missing `src/libmongoc/src/common/common-b64.lo` or the binary which is the file isnt installed

Comment: You dockerfile and your docker version please.

Comment: dockerfile 
`FROM php:8.0.10-alpine
    && \
        pecl install mongodb \
        pecl clear-cache \
    && \
        echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mongodb.ini; \
`
Docker version 19.03.13

Comment: Where you able to solve this Ana? Or anyone for that matter??I' currently struggling with this exact same issue with php:74-cli-alpine and php8.0-cli-alpine Just in case anyone ask `RUN set -xe \
  && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    openssl-dev \
  && pecl install \
    mongodb \
  && docker-php-ext-enable \
    mongodb \
  && apk del .build-deps \
  && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/cache/apk/* /usr/share/php`

Comment: same problem here.